# In Allegro CL and ABCL, can I construct a struct given only its type name?

Tags: common-lisp, allegro-cl, abcl

In most implementations, you can use `(make-instance 'struct-type)` to create a struct regardless of whether you defined a constructor function for that type. This doesn't work on Allegro or ABCL, but those implementations can still create structs at read-time with `#S(struct-type)`, which makes me think there must be some other way to construct them at runtime given the type name as a symbol.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Declarative specifications for generating test data: https://github.com/DalekBaldwin/check-it#struct-generator . I was hoping for simple, portable ways to get extract the information I need through introspection, but I'm prepared to go under the hood and handle each implementation separately if it comes down to that.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mix structure and object creation.  The standard defined [`make-instance`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_ins.htm) for `standard-class`, and for `symbol` such that the provided symbol is passed to `find-class`, then `make-instance` recurses.

As such, a stock implementation that extends `make-instance` for named structure types is not conforming, and neither is your code if you rely on it.

Then, [`#S` is specified](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhm.htm) to work correctly only if the structure has a standard constructor, so there's not much magic left there.

Given this restriction, you could implement `#S` yourself by interning a symbol named `make-` concatenated with the structure name, followed by the keyword argument list.

But again, the implementation dependent details hit.  You ask about when there's no constructor, which implies `:constructor nil` in `defstruct`.  Note that not specifying the constructor argument means it'll have a default constructor.  The implementation can have internal bookkeeping, including a hidden standard constructor that it creates regardless of your options (or a parameterless constructor and slot accessors) to be used in [`make-load-form-using-slots`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_l_1.htm), an extended `#S`, and possibly to optimize literal structure loading (as opposed to forms that create one) in file compilation through [`make-load-form`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_ld_.htm)'s specialization for structures.

Comment: So if I'm reading you right, there's no way to portably ask for a list of available constructors? I'd like to get your thoughts on my proposed solution too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030304/in-allegro-cl-and-abcl-can-i-construct-a-struct-given-only-its-type-name/30042130#30042130

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not very elegant, but whats about:

```
(defun make-struct-by-name (name &rest args)
  (apply (symbol-function
          (intern (concatenate 'string "MAKE-"
                               (symbol-name name))))
         args))
```

Usage:

```
CL-USER> (defstruct foo
           a b)
FOO

CL-USER> (make-struct-by-name 'foo :a 1 :b 2)
#S(FOO :A 1 :B 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of one potential solution, but it's a bit of a hack. Since the `#S` reader macro works but I can't find out how ABCL and Allegro implement it (it may be totally internal to the implementation and not defined in Lisp), I can at least generate a string and programmatically invoke the reader macro function on it:

```
(defun make-struct-from-type (type-name)
  (with-input-from-string
      (s (format nil "(~A::~A)"
                 (package-name (symbol-package type-name))
                 (symbol-name type-name)))
    (funcall (get-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\S)
             s #\S nil)))
```

This might not work on other implementations though. SBCL complains about `sb-impl::*read-buffer*` being unbound, so it may require a little more finessing to trick the implementation into thinking the reader macro is being invoked in a typical context.

This should invoke the default constructor even if it was given a name without the default `make-` prefix.

Comment: That SBCL behavior is a bug.  As you show, one might want to exercise a dispatch macro character's function out of the reader context.  A workaround is to use `(read s)` instead of calling the dispatch macro character function yourself.

Comment: Even so, this gets you struct creation, but not initialization.